# dynamically creating query in a loop

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I"m looping through a table trying to create a dynamic sql query. It appears to work fine except when I'm concatenating results to make the actual statement. Psudo code follows

```
WHILE (Data is in the table)
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1 @result = result from table

@sql = @sql + ', ' + @result

END
```

If I look at `@sql` in each loop I see the expected results, but when the loop is finished `@sql` is empty. Can someone explain why?

Comment: syntax in the OP appears malformed. can I suggest executing sample code at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and re-posting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your pseudo-code is a good approximation of what your actual code is doing, you'd need something like:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = '';
WHILE (Data is in the table)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @result = result from table;

    @sql = @sql + ', ' + @result;

END
```

If you don't initialize `@sql` to a zero-length string prior to the loop, SQL Server will attempt to append `@result` to a NULL string, which results in a NULL string, hence the `@sql` at the end of the loop will appear empty.

Comment: Missing `SET` on the second-last line. But why not just `SELECT @sql = @sql + ',' + result FROM table;`?

Comment: Agreed, @AaronBertrand - however I was working with the OP's pseudo-code and only wanted to show the change that was necessary for his desired result.  If the OP updates the question to reflect actual code, I will of course modify my version.  I actually was contemplating adding a "real" version, but decided against it without more effort from the OP.